# Try-Catch block termination

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm using a try-catch block to catch any exceptions that might be thrown when I run certain methods on a stack.  My code for the pop method looks like this:

```
public T pop()
{   
    T temp = null;
    try
    {
        temp = first.data;

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println("Invalid operation on an empty stack");

    }
    first = first.next;
    return temp;
}
```

When I run the program the exception is caught... my terminal produces this:
(menu choice 'd' is the pop method)

> Please enter a menu choice:  d
>
> Invalid operation on an empty stack
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at MyStack.pop(MyStack.java:58)
>           at StackTest.main(StackTest.java:52)

so I think my exception is being caught since it prints "Invalid operation...", but my program also terminates when the exception is thrown.  Any help?

Comment: You may have swallowed the first exception from first.data, but what if first was null? Then first.next would throw another NPE

Comment: I am almost sure your `first` is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have learned a very valuable lesson today:  **don't catch `Exception` without good reason.**

The problem here is that `first` is coming back `null`, so we're going to throw that exception once we try to dereference it.

Let's look at it from a different angle.  If `first` is null, we know we can't pop anything, so we should be *throwing* the exception instead.

```
public T pop() {
    if(first == null) {
        throw new EmptyStackException("Invalid operation on empty stack");
    }

    T value = first.data;
    first = first.next;
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I originally had your exact code, but by throwing an exception won't my program automatically terminate?  I'm trying to make it so the program will still run after displaying the error message.

Comment: Catch it a layer up.  That is to say, catch it when you try to pop the value (have your `try...catch` block wrap the execution of `pop`).  There's nothing from the stack's perspective that it can do if it doesn't have any data in it and you want to take data from it.

Comment: I instead created my own exception that extends the runtimeexception and put my error message in there while throwing the exception instead of the try-catch block.  worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there's another exception being thrown, *after* your catch block. It is very likely that `first` is null. That causes the catch block to be executed (because `first.data` is a null pointer exception), but it also causes another null pointer exception at

```
first = first.next;
```

Thus you have an uncaught exception. How you tackle this is up to you; it's more of a design decision than a correctness one.

The simplest and probably correct option is to do *all* of your modification inside the try block, so if something goes wrong you don't resume operations that probably won't work.

```
public T pop(){   
    T temp = null;
    try{
        temp = first.data;
        first = first.next;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Invalid operation on an empty stack");
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Of course, the `try..catch` construction isn't really appropriate here. A much more succinct way to write the same method would be:

```
public T pop(){   
    if(first == null) return null;

    //By virtue of reaching this point, first is necessarily non-null.
    T temp = first.data;
    first = first.next;
    return temp;
}
```

But if the goal was to experiment with `try..catch` use my top answer.

Answer (score 1):

`first` is clearly `null` based on your output. Now, you're catching the `NullPointerException` that arises from `temp  = first.data`, but not the one that arises from `first = first.next` (since that assignment is not enclosed with a `try` block):

```
public T pop()
{   
    T temp = null;
    try
    {
        temp = first.data;  // <-- you catch the exception thrown here

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println("Invalid operation on an empty stack");

    }
    first = first.next;  // <-- but you don't catch the one thrown here
    return temp;
}
```

In general it's a *very* bad idea to catch a `NullPointerException`; explicitly check for `null` beforehand.

Comment: It's also a very bad idea to work with nulls in the first place. Consider `Optional<T>` (in Java 8) or similar datatypes in libraries such as functionaljava or Guava

Answer (score 0):

It's highly likely that your first is null.

Try this code instead

```
public T pop()
{   
    T temp = null;
    try 
    {
        if (first != null) 
        {
            temp = first.data;
            first = first.next;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println("Invalid operation on an empty stack");

    }
    return temp;
}
```